# Data in table row not aligned

Tags: tables

I have a pretty complicated table that gathers some decisions inside of it. I recently added a new column to the table, which did not disrupt it, but some of the rows filled with the data for the new column behave in a strange way:

[image]

Take a look at the last column. You can see it doesn't have a "+" for the "Linear" entry. The problem arise when I add a "+" there:

[image]

As you can see, the "+" for the last column is not aligned correctly with the rest of the "+"s. The important thing to notice is that I **did not** change the code of the table, I simply added a new column as I always do when I need to add a new column entry.

As you can imagine the code of this table is simply huge, thus I don't think it is feasible to paste it here. If you need me to paste a small portion of it I can modify this post and add it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}


\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty = 10000

% Document starts
\begin{document}

\title{title something}
\maketitle
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\small

    \definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.90}
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{light-gray}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.504\textwidth}{c|l%b{23mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            %|x{2.2mm}
            |c?{0.3mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            %|x{2.2mm}
            |c?{0.3mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
            %|c
            %|l
            |x{2.2mm}
        |
    }
    &
    \textbf{something}, something 
        & \begin{sideways}
        b
            (2003)
        \end{sideways} 
        & \begin{sideways}
        c
            (2003)
        \end{sideways} 
        & \begin{sideways}
        d
            (2005)
        \end{sideways} 
        & \begin{sideways}
        e
            (2006)
        \end{sideways}
        & \begin{sideways}
        f
            (2007)
        \end{sideways}
         & \begin{sideways}
        g
            (2008)
        \end{sideways}
        & \begin{sideways}
        h
            (2010)
        \end{sideways}
        & \begin{sideways}
        i
            (2011)
       \end{sideways}
    \tabularnewline

    \hline 
    \hline
 &
%\multirow{9}{1cm}{Design Time Issues} &
        \textbf{something}  


                & 
                & 
                & 
                &
                &

                &
                &
                &





            \tabularnewline &
            \hspace{0.5mm} something



                                    &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +               &
                    +

            \tabularnewline &
            \hspace{0.5mm} something

                                    & %g
                    +               & %h
                    +               & %i
                    +               & %j
                    +               & %k
                    +               & %l
                    +               & %m
                    +               & %n
                    +                %o
            \tabularnewline &
            \hspace{0.5mm} something

                                    & %g
                    +               & %h
                    +               & %i
                    +               & %j
                    +               & %k
                                    & %l
                    +               & %m
                    +               & %n
                    +                %o
            \tabularnewline &
            \hspace{0.5mm} something

                                    & %g
                                    & %h
                                    & %i
                    +               & %j
                                    & %k
                                    & %l
                                    & %m
                                    & %n
                                     %o
        \tabularnewline    
\hline 

    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    \caption{something}
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post, but please make your code compilable (begining with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). Also it would be good, if you can shorten your table as far as possible (so that your layout problem still occurs).

Comment: Edited and reduced!

Comment: Try to further shorten your MWE, for example by removing all unnecessary columns. Also many of the packages, the title page etc. are superfluous.

Comment: Edited! Smaller than this in terms of number of columns, the error solves itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by superfluous empty lines in your tabular. Just delete them

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}

    \begin{table*}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.761\textwidth}{x{2.2mm}|x{2.2mm}}
            + & + 
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{without empty line}
    \end{table*}



    \begin{table*}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.761\textwidth}{x{2.2mm}|x{2.2mm}}
            + & + 

        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{with empty line}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which empty lines are you addressing exactly?

Comment: The one after the line which is not displayed correctly. Or simply delete all.